# Taking control of downloads without using Browser Extensions

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, download-manager

I've seen download manager programs including IDM taking control of downloads in browsers without having extensions in them and they are calling it (Advanced Browser Integration).
I was wondering if anyone can suggest an approach for a similar situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDM only works on Windows and does his *Advanced Browser Integration* tricks using `Windows Filtering Platform` which is a windows specific service.

If you want to do something similar on Windows, you should study that platform.

On unix systems, as far as I know, there isn't anything like the Windows Filtering Platform. Packet filtering and other firewall like functionality happens in the kernel and there are multiple implementations of that: which is running (if any) depends on how the user decided to configure the system (even if `ipf` is almost guaranteed to be the used one on BSD and BSD derived systems).

On Mac Os X specifically you probably want to check `Network Kernel Extensions`. I'm not sure they are sufficient to do what you want to do, but I suspect they are.